# generate snake lower case outputs from bash scripts

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a bash script which takes in query and generates the json. I am looking to generate the new json format as

```
{ "symbols" : "my_name"
  "nid" : "MyName"
}
```

Could you please help me in modifying this query

```
QUERY='SELECT row_to_json(o) FROM (SELECT nid , nid(????) as symbols FROM batch_types ORDER BY id::integer) AS o';
echo $QUERY | psql -h localhost -U report mcore -t $@ | jq -s '.' > generated/enum/batch_type.json
```

I am expecting some sed after jq as `jq -s '.' | sed "..."`.

I am getting data from PostgreSQL.

Example:

Output from sql could be `

```
[
 {"name" : "Xml"
  "symbol" : "Xml"
 },
{ "name": "Java",
  "symbols": "Java"
}
]
```

to

```
[
 {"name" : "Xml"
  "symbol" : "xml"
 },
{ "name": "Java",
  "symbols": "java"
}
]
```

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/.*/\L&/'`

Comment: as mentioned, want to get snake case and not all lower case using sed.

Comment: [edit] your question to include **clear** concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now it looks like you want to change Xml to xml and Java to java in some parts of your file but idk what that has to do with snake case or the first sample json so your question ie very unclear and your posted sample input/output (assuming that's what it is) doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get using
 `sed -r '/symbol/ s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1_\L\2/g' | awk '/^\{*[[:blank:]]*"symbol[s]?"[[:blank:]]*:/{ $0=tolower($0);}1'''`

Thanks everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{print tolower($0)}' >outfile
```

awk [[ manpage ]](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) says:

> `tolower(str)`
>   Return a copy of the string str, with  all  the
>   ppercase characters in str translated to their corresponding 
>   lowercase  counterparts.Non-alphabetic characters are left unchanged.

**Edit**

If you're trying to convert only the "symbols" value to lowercase, use the below :

```
...jq -s '.' |  awk '/^\{*[[:blank:]]*"symbol[s]?"[[:blank:]]*:/{
$0=tolower($0);}1'' >outfile
```

**Output**

```
[
 {"name" : "Xml"
  "symbol" : "xml"
 },
{ "name": "Java",
  "symbols": "java"
}
]
```

---

<sup>**Sidenote:** `?` with awk-regex is for utmost one match which would match either `symbol` or `symbols` in this case.</sup>

Comment: could you please elaborate how is it working as I only need to generate symbols field in that way...thanks

Comment: @AnimeshJain : This information was not given in the question, so please update the question. Give possible input and expected output. See the update

Comment: Thanks...but above seems to be not working...may be because of variable spaces ??

Comment: @AnimeshJain : See the edit in the second part of the answer

Comment: Not working when I have like DataFeed which I want as data_feed

Comment: Where is the above point mentioned in the question? Should I divine and find that out?